# How to add callback after registration with Rails3 and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback, devise

How to add a callback to create an account for the registered user.

Devise files (registrations_controller.rb) are under controllers/devise
My user model has has_many :accounts relationship (and the account model has belongs_to :user)

First I don't know where to add the callback (what file?)

Then, how to automatically create a new account with the right user_id of the registered user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

You can override devise's registration controller, add callback to create account using filters. Remember to name the file registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  after_filter :add_account 

  protected

  def add_account
    if resource.persisted? # user is created successfuly
      resource.accounts.create(attributes_for_account)
    end
 end
end
```

then in your routes.rb tell devise to use overrided controller for registration

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations'}
```

Comment: In my case, I needed to access params, so I went with this approach rather than the model's after_create.

Comment: Need to add #attributes_for_account method, something like  def attributes_for_account  params.require(:account).permit([:name, :surname, :contact_nr]) end

Answer (score 2):

Here's a thread on the google group that answers your question:

http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/6fc2df8d71f8b2f0

Basically it recommends just adding a standard rails "after_create" method to your user model to run the code you need.

Comment: What if you need to access the params hash, to process additional data?  For example, user can have many group memberships. User signs up with a invitation code for a group.  Upon creating the user, create the group membership, determining the group by looking at the invitation code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using both approaches.

after_create in the model to create associated data and
`after_filter :send_notification_mailer, only: :create`
In the RegistrationsController (same as @naveed)

because in the after_create callback I was receiving the error exception

`ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Couldn't find User with id`

when sending with Active Job the confirmation email in background with sidekiq because the user it was not persisted sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

First, open your version of devise with `bundle open devise`. Check out the app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb. You will probably see a method called in the create method when a user successfully registers. For my version (3.5.2) it is `sign_up`.

In routes, you'll need

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

The you can define your own RegistrationsController like so:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController    
  protected

  def sign_up(_resource_name, user)
    super
    # do your stuff here
  end
end
```