# Rails 3 - Devise: how to create a single page to publish an Article and Sigin + Signup

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have the following relationship

- User  --> has_many: Articles
- Article  --> belongs_to: User

I need to create a public (not restricted) page to Publish an Article (with Title & Description), in the same page I need to add the SignIn / SignUp form (with the possibility to switch bitween the SignIn and SignUp with ajax).

After click to the Publish "Button", the behaviour is quite the same for SignIn and SignUp:

- SignUp, the Article will be inserted as "Draft", and we will send an email to inform
- SignIn, the Article will be inserted as "Draft", and we will send an email to complete the registration form

Which is the best approach?

Regards

Comment: Hi - can you provide details on what problem you are facing when you try to do this?

Comment: We are quite new in Rails, and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this thread:

[How to add callback after registration with Rails3 and Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702806/how-to-add-callback-after-registration-with-rails3-and-devise)

The key is, don't look to Devise, use callbacks on your model(s) and Rails nested forms for sending the data.

Also note, the **authentication** layer for Devise is Warden, which does have callbacks for sign in/out.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too generic for this format.  But here is what I can suggest.  Check out a few railscasts.  Start with this as I think it is closest to what you are looking at for front-end:

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
```