# Rails & Devise: How can I trigger other events when user registers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

For example a visitor will create an account I want to be able to trigger and create other things with those parameters until they confirm or login.

This is the closest solution I have, if it's not efficient please it would be great to give any suggestion

In `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   #other stuff
   after_filter :trigger_me, if: :devise_controller?
     def trigger_me
       #some code to execute
       #Some way to get User info just created.
     end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better way to handle this would be in your User model through after_create [callback(s)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) OR the other option if you need access to everything in the params hash would be to override the Devise RegistrationsController and add a callback to it, like discussed here: [How to add callback after registration with Rails3 and Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702806/how-to-add-callback-after-registration-with-rails3-and-devise).

Comment: any idea how can I actually access the user attributes ?

Comment: Accessing user attributes in a model callback or params hash in the overridden controller callback?

Comment: in the overridden controller callback, thank you so much, I figured it out, it's the `resource`itself. It contains the user parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method `#after_sign_in_path_for` in your ApplicationController.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#after_sign_in_path_for-instance_method

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(resource) ||
      if resource.is_a?(User) && resource.country.nil?
        edit_user_path resource
      else
        super
      end
  end
```

Then redirect or do other stuff based on the user (resource) values. After the user registers, they are 'signed in', but not confirmed.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

> After signing in a user, confirming the account or updating the password, Devise will look for a scoped root path to redirect to. For instance, when using a :user resource, the user_root_path will be used if it exists; otherwise, the default root_path will be used. This means that you need to set the root inside your routes:
>
> `root to: 'home#index'`
>
> You can also override after_sign_in_path_for and after_sign_out_path_for to customize your redirect hooks.

You can also define the `user_root_path` and do stuff in the method it points to.